# Spring netflix eureka, zuul vs Spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to the microservice world. Would like to know when to use Spring eureka, zuul vs spring data flow.

I am building a service which in turns will consume multiple granular services(aka micro service), aggregate all the data and returns aggregated data to the consumer. All the services will run in local intranet within company infrastructure. Also, I would like to load balance individual microservices.

What should be the choice of technology for microservices deployment?

I am using Spring 4.3, Spring boot, Rest, Spring data.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest this architecture:

1. Netflix Eureka : for Service discovery
2. Consul or Config Server : for saving configurations in environment base on 12 factors
3. Zuul : for Intelligent and programmable routing
4. Netflix Ribbon : for Client-Side Load Balancing
5. Zipkin : for tracing
6. Turbine : for metrics aggregation
7. Netflix Feign : for Declarative REST API implementation
8. Hysterix : for circuit breaker (one of the EIP patterns)
9. RabbitMQ (Spring-AMQP) or Kafka (Spring-Kafka and Kafka Stream) for having asynchronous communication style
10. Grafana + Prometheus + Prometheus-jmx-exporter for monitoring system
11. Docker : for virtualization and container base architecure
12. Docker Swarm or Kubernetes : for scalability, automation and Container Management

note : Prometheus is a time-series database (including monitoring features) you can also use InfluxDb or Graphite  instead of it.

Comment: A diagram would be nice :))

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place to start with is to read through the overview of all these projects [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) to get a better understanding of the objectives each of these projects achieve.

Comment: I would like to do following, multiple instances of services which accepts requests via rest controller and these services should be load balanced and can be accessed via one URL just like how application server load balancer works. Could you please suggest some set of tools for the same. I understand Eureka can be used for Service registry and discovery but what will be other tools.